# Are sequences in $O(1/n)$ which are not in $O(n^{-1-\varepsilon})$ also in $\Theta(1/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I'm in the situation in where I have a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in[0,\infty)$ and already know that it satisfies the following to properties:

- There is some $C>0$ such that $x_n \leq \frac{C}{n}$, which I think means $(x_n) \in O(1/n)$.
- If $\varepsilon > 0$ there can't be some $D>0$ with $x_n \leq \frac{D}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now I wish to show that there is also some $C' > 0 $ such that $x_n \geq \frac{C'}{n}$. My intuition tells me that this should be correct by I can't think of a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's possible to have a sequence that shrinks faster than $\frac{1}{n}$ but slower than any $n^{-1-\epsilon}$. E.g. $\frac{1}{nln(n)}$.